# want to hide image when image is not found at the src location?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

```
jQuery('img').bind('error',function(){
            alert('hi');
        jQuery(this).hide(); 
        });
```

I have written this code but non available images are not hiding and still showing cross sign. Can anybody point out what can be wrong. I am writing this under document.ready and i have tried it under window.onload as well.

Comment: Have you tried loading the img src on jQuery(Document).ready() and checking if it finds it there?  Just an idea

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem seems to be that by the time you bind your error event, the image's onerror has already fired. You can fire it again by resetting the img.src after binding the event. The following worked on IE8, FF, and Chrome.

```
$('img').error(function(){
    alert('hi');
    $(this).hide(); 
});

$('img').each(function() { this.src = this.src; });
```

jsFiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/7cnQN/

Comment: Wow, good thinking.  This will however reload images that did load correctly as well, which depending on how many image you have and how you have caching setup, could increase load time.

Comment: @Barlow - I completely agree. I should have made it clear that I didn't think it was a great idea, but was more an explanation of why the event wasn't firing. If you have appropriate cache directives, the reload shouldn't be a big deal because it should be served from your local browser cache. Without those, you're looking at another server round-trip per image to determine that it hasn't changed.

Comment: Genius would be the right word i guess. It solved my problem thanks. Would be great if u explain a little more what is happening here.

Comment: @James sorry to trouble again. How can i use .live as well since many of my images come from ajax calls.

Comment: @Sushil - Order of events... Browser loads bad image. Browser raises img.onerror. You hook up your $('img').error() handler, but nothing happens because the img.onerror has already occurred. By resetting the source of each image, the browser will re-raise the error and your code will get called. As I mentioned above, make sure your images have cache directives set so that you don't force another round-trip to the server for all images on your page.

Comment: You can just use $('img').live('error', ...). $('img').error() is just syntactic sugar for $('img').bind('error', ...).

Answer (score 2):

Tested in FF, IE, Chrome, Safari, Opera.

```
$('img').each(function() {
    var img = this;
    if (img.complete) {
        if (typeof img.naturalWidth != "undefined" && img.naturalWidth == 0) {
            console.log(img, 'load failed');
        } else {
            console.log(img, 'load ok');
        }
    } else if (img.readyState == 'uninitialized') {
        console.log('load failed - IE');
    } else {
        $(img).error(function() { console.log(img, 'load failed - error()'); });
        $(img).ready(function() { console.log(img, 'load ok - onload()'); });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

On both `jQuery(document).ready()` and `jQuery(window).onload()` the img will have already had the error, so you are binding to error too late.  Try using:

```
jQuery('img').live('error',function(){
            alert('hi');
        jQuery(this).hide(); 
        });
```

before jQuery(document).ready();

I haven't tried this code yet (and wouldn't have time too for a while)  Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I personally have issues with JQuery, as it seems to stop people looking into JavaScript's native capabilities.  I would personally use the **onerror** event, e.g.:

`myimage.onerror = function() { this.style.visibility = 'hidden'; }`

(not tested)

Comment: jQuery does a lot of things in a very nice way, encapsulating in to a far more functional style many of the basic features.  The choice to use it should be made on the need for the feature set.  If all you need is an error handler like the above, then it seems unnecessary.  As your code and Barlow Tuckers achieve pretty much the same thing.  Except his binds to all images and does `display: none;` rather than `visibility: hidden;` (I'll ignore the `alert()`!)

Comment: I agree that in basic functionality using native javascript a better option.  However, there are many times that jQuery (or other frameworks) both saves time and increase readability.

Answer (score 0):

The example on the [`.error()`](http://api.jquery.com/error/) docs show this:

```
$("img").error(function(){
  $(this).hide();
});
```

... which is essentially the same as what you're doing. Can you verify that jQuery is loaded and available on the page? Also, if you're using FireFox, Chrome or Safari, try checking your javascript console for errors.

EDIT: Note this also, from the docs:

> This event may not be correctly fired when the page is served locally. Since error relies on normal HTTP status codes, it will generally not be triggered if the URL uses the file: protocol.

Are you testing this locally?

Comment: yes i tried this at first. But this also doesnt works. Although on one particular page some of the image hide. But others still show cross sign.

Comment: Where are the images being served from? Locally or from a remote server?

Comment: images are server from my local apache server.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try a different tactic and instead show the images when they load:

```
jQuery('img').each(function(i,img){
    jQuery('img').bind('load',function(){ this.show(); });
    if (img.complete)
        jQuery(img).show();
});
```

First bind to the event, then check to see if the image has already loaded (.complete) and show it.  This will require you to hide all of the images before-hand with a script or within the inline style of the individual images.  Using a known container as a scope...

```
jQuery('#container img')
```

...you can limit this behavior to a subset of the images.

Answer (score 0):

You dealing with a race condition.  jQuery may or may not have been loaded when the image is loaded.  The following code handles both cases.

```
$('img').each(function() {
    var img = this;
    if (img.complete) {
        if (typeof img.naturalWidth != "undefined" && img.naturalWidth == 0) {
            console.log(img, 'load failed');
        } else {
            console.log(img, 'load ok');
        }
    } else {
        $(img).error(function() { console.log(img, 'load failed - error()'); });
        $(img).ready(function() { console.log(img, 'load ok - onload()'); });
    }
});
```